# Apply a correction to only some datapoints in a timeseries, identified by rapid drop in values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am stuck on this problem. 
I have a time series of light intensity, my problem is that at a relatively low intensity the sensor response rolls over resulting in a sudden drop in values. I need to apply a correction to only those data points within this rollover period.

You can see the effect on the attached figure, light increases in the morning and then as values reach 2.0, they drop off sharply. I have correction factors that I can apply. I am having issues figuring out how to identify which points to correct and then applying the correction

[Figure showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eipOW.png)

So far I have used np.diff and np.argwhere to calculate the difference between successive points and to identify the start and end row numbers for each of those sudden drops and recoveries. I am now stuck on how to take that information and use it to apply the correction data between those row numbers.

```
 array = abs(np.diff(MS9dataWB7, axis=0)) >= 1.2
```

returns an np array true and false for np.diff >=1.2

```
 result = np.argwhere(array)
```

returns row numbers where condition is true

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

having a small sample data set would be very helpful. In the future please try to post a minimum, verifiable snippet of sample code that reproduces the issue - that way we can test our own half-baked ideas before posting them :).

You are on the right track but I think you have a couple of issues to consider. The general plan is to identify the points that need correcting, then add the correction term. You've attempted the first step by using np.diff(). However, this is only going to find the first point that changes by 1.2. The immediately adjacent point to the right also needs to be corrected but the diff between the first two "bad" points is no longer 1.2. So you'll miss identifying the 2nd and subsequent points. Then on the last "bad" point of the day you'll end up flagging the first "good" point as bad (because the abs(diff) is > 1.2 again as it bounces back up) and you'll over correct the "good" point.

First I'll generate some fake sample data that consists of a sine wave with a period of 1 day. I'm using pandas because it's very friendly for working with time series data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

devicedatetime = pd.date_range('2018-05-01', '2018-05-03', freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame(devicedatetime, columns=['datetime'])
df['elapsedtime'] = df['datetime'] - df['datetime'].iloc[0]
df['elapsedseconds'] = df['elapsedtime'] / pd.Timedelta('1s')
df['data'] =  1 + np.sin(2*np.pi * df['elapsedseconds']/86400.0)
df.head()
```

Now I have a pandas dataframe with my original time tags and my sample data. The elapsedtime and elapsedseconds columns exist only to facilitate calculating the fake data. You can plot the result using

```
df.plot('datetime', `data')
```

The next step is to identify the 'bad' points. I'll build an array of boolean values based on my test conditions. Just eyeballing your data, it appears that you only want to look at data with a time > 17:00 and less than 05:00. As a safety net you could also add a condition that examines the data value itself.

```
bad_data = (df['datetime'].dt.hour > 17) | (df['datetime'].dt.hour < 5)
```

Now I can calculate the corrected data values. My correction was to simply add 3 to the value.

```
df['fixeddata'] = np.where(bad_data, df['data'] + 3, df['data'])
df.plot(x='datetime', y=['data', 'fixeddata'])
```